# What is the RSpec equivalent of Behat profiles

Tags: ruby, rspec, behat

I need to alter env variables eg URLS, depending on the environment (alpha, beta, and public/ops) in which the tests are to be run. Are "contexts" within RSpec that allow for this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the problem you try to solve. Normally RSpec runs in only in the `test` environment, not in multople environments.

Your `test` environment is defined in `config/environments/test.rb`. In than file you define everything that is valid for all kind of tests. For example you will never ever want to send emails from your test suite. Therefore you will find something like this in that file:

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

If there is something that you want to change in your specs (if DelayedJobs should be available or not in the following example), then there are multiple ways to do so. The one I see most is to stub objects to return the values you need for a certain test:

```
describe 'a complex operation' do
  context 'with DelayedJobs' do
    # acts like DelayedJobs are configured to run in background
    before { Delayed::Worker.stub(:delay_jobs => true) }

    it 'creates a DelayedJob' do
      ...
    end
  end

  context 'without DelayedJobs' do
    # acts like DelayedJobs are configured to run immediately  
    before { Delayed::Worker.stub(:delay_jobs => false) }

    it 'calls the complex query' do
      ...
    end
  end
end
```